# CUDA documentation does not mention compatibility requirements for Debian systems

Tags: linux, cuda, debian, compatibility

I often need to recall the compatibility between host and device compilers and refer to the documentation page
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements

The table in there does not mention the Debian distribution at all, though. 
This seems odd to me, for Debian is a reputable and popular Linux distribution.

[image]

Is there a rational for this at least nominal absence, and how should one work around it? 
In other words: given a CUDA version and a Debian system, how can I obtain the corresponding compatible versions of kernel, gcc version and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I obtain the corresponding compatible versions of kernel, gcc version and so on?

There aren't any.

CUDA isn't supported by NVIDIA for use on Debian as a development environment.  The support footprint as you've already pointed out is spelled out (for linux) in [the linux install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html), in the table you excerpted, and absence from the table means that item (distro, kernel version, gcc version, etc.) is not officially supported.

The rationale for this is that each additional linux distro supported increases CUDA support costs.  One example of this is in QA costs.  Each CUDA release has a huge test matrix associated with it, and adding a new linux distro essentially increases the dimensionality of that test matrix.  These costs have to be considered against the benefit of supporting that particular distro.  As more distros are supported, there are decreasing returns on investment.

I won't be able to give a detailed answer on the specific business cost/benefit analysis as it pertains to Debian specifically, and that is not really a programming question anyway.

If you'd like to see a change in CUDA, whether it be functionality, documentation, support, etc., you're encouraged to file a bug to express your desires/concerns at http://developer.nvidia.com    The specific process to file a bug (not a programming question anyway) but it is easy to discover;  [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044668/cuda-programming-and-performance/-how-to-report-a-bug/) is a current link to the process description.

We can generalize this answer to other similar questions of why a particular environment is not supported in CUDA. (For example, Linux Mint is not officially supported, neither is Scientific Linux.) The concepts discussed here are not unique to Debian, and similar comments could be made about a wide variety of compatibility scenarios.

I'm trying to address the question of why similar information for Debian is not present in the table excerpted in the question.  I'm not intending to answer the question "is there any way to use CUDA on Debian?" which I view as a separate question.  For that one, google is your friend, but there is no official statement of support or compatibility with Debian.